# Could NOT find Boost (missing: unit_test_framework)

Tags: cmake

I have downloaded a github project made it in C++. And I need to generate a solution (.sln) using CMake. But I failed as I've wrote in the post title:

```
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: unit_test_framework) (found version
  "1.75.0")
```

Here is the original CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS unit_test_framework REQUIRED)

include(CTest)

enable_testing()

add_executable(unit-test unit_test.cpp)

target_link_libraries(unit-test cpool ${Boost_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY})

add_test(unit-test unit-test --show_progress=yes --log_format=XML --log_sink=cpool.xml --log_level=all --report_level=no)

add_custom_target(test
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
    COMMENT "Starting to run unit tests ..."
    COMMAND bla bla bla
    DEPENDS unit-test USES_TERMINAL
)
```

Got that error. Then I tried:

```
SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH} "C:/Program Files/boost_1_75_0/boost")
SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} "C:/Program Files/boost_1_75_0/lib64-msvc-14.1")

FIND_PACKAGE(Boost)
IF (Boost_FOUND)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
    ADD_DEFINITIONS( "-DHAS_BOOST" )
ENDIF()

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS unit_test_framework REQUIRED)

include(CTest)

enable_testing()

add_executable(unit-test unit_test.cpp)

target_link_libraries(unit-test cpool ${Boost_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY})

add_test(unit-test unit-test --show_progress=yes --log_format=XML --log_sink=cpool.xml --log_level=all --report_level=no)

add_custom_target(test
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
    COMMENT "Starting to run unit tests ..."
    COMMAND bla bla bla
    DEPENDS unit-test USES_TERMINAL
)
```

The same error. I don't have much experience in CMake, could you help me to make it ?

P.S. I have installed boost in the following location:

[image]

P.S. I have tried also:

```
set(BOOST_ROOT "C:/Program Files/boost_1_75_0")

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS unit_test_framework REQUIRED)

include(CTest)

enable_testing()

add_executable(unit-test unit_test.cpp)

target_link_libraries(unit-test cpool ${Boost_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY})

add_test(unit-test unit-test --show_progress=yes --log_format=XML --log_sink=cpool.xml --log_level=all --report_level=no)

add_custom_target(test
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
    COMMENT "Starting to run unit tests ..."
    COMMAND bla bla bla
    DEPENDS unit-test USES_TERMINAL
)
```

The same outcome.

Comment: You might be better off using `set(Boost_ROOT "C:/Program Files/boost_1_75_0")` before doing `find_package(Boost COMPONENTS unit_test_framework REQUIRED)` than adding include and library dirs to `CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH` and `CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH`. Make sure to delete the cache (i.e. CMakeCache.txt) before rerunning cmake.

Comment: I have updated the post.

Comment: OK, then please add `set(Boost_DBUG ON)` before your find_package call, delete cache, rerun cmake and add the output (or at least relevant parts) to your post. Please also add the compiler you're using, the CMake version number and whether you build Boost binaries by yourself or downloaded it (which version did you chose frome here? https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.75.0/ ) .

Comment: What I meant was `set(Boost_DEBUG ON)`

Comment: The issue was that 'lib' folder has different name, soon as I renamed correctly, with yours set(BOOST_ROOT "C:/Program Files/boost_1_75_0")
set(Boost_DBUG ON)
 everything was alright. Thank you !